# Getting Exception while sending repeated messages to TCPClient worker thread for broadcasting

Tags: java, android, multithreading

The main thread of my application is continously generating string data, which is to be sent to TCPCLient worker thread, to be sent over the socket.

This is my TCPClient :

```
public class TCPClient extends Thread
{
    String ip;
    int port;
    PrintWriter out;
    Handler handler;

    TCPClient(String ip, int port)
    {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip,port);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("OKLINUX","Exception while creating socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                Log.d("OKLINUX","Data sent : "+msg.obj.toString());
                out.println(msg.obj.toString());
                out.flush();
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

On my main thread :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sender = new TCPClient("192.168.0.7",2016);
        sender.start();

        //some other code

       //inside some sort of loop
       {
           Message msg = Message.obtain();
           msg.obj = "some string";
           sender.handler.sendMessage(msg);
       }
}
```

The stacktrace says `IllegalStateException : This msg is already in use`. Why is it so? I believe Looper will assign new messages from queue when they are available and handler will be called for each seperate message.

This is the stacktrace :

```
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484): Process: info.androidhive.speechtotext, PID: 16484
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {info.androidhive.speechtotext/info.androidhive.speechtotext.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: { when=-1ms what=108 obj=hello target=info.androidhive.speechtotext.TCPClient$1 } This message is already in use.
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3659)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3702)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:155)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: { when=-1ms what=108 obj=hello target=info.android.speechtotext.TCPClient$1 } This message is already in use.
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:320)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:507)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at info.androidhive.speechtotext.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:83)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6218)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3655)
06-24 00:56:35.180: E/AndroidRuntime(16484):    ... 10 more
```

**EDIT**

It runs fine on the first time. The crash happens for the second message.

Comment: how can you assign a `String` to `arg1` if it's defined as an `int`?

Comment: @user0815 : Sorry... that was a typo. See the new code.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864990/problem-in-handler-with-messages-in-android) question... seems like one of the solutions could solve your problem.

Comment: @user0815 : Thanks.. actually I stumbled upon this question only few seconds before you answered and it did solve my problem... Thanks

Comment: so how did you solve it? `msg.obj = new String();`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HandlerThread and initialize handler in onLooperPrepared (),from stack trace it seems like looper cant dispatch message, I think because looper isnt initialized